# block IP address using SpamAssassin

Tags: iptables, ip, postfix, spamassasin

Does using "Trusted Networks" in SpamAssasins local.cf 
in a way so you use a ! before a IP address, block the given IP address?

The [documentation](https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html#network_test_options) is not clear regarding this issue.

Does

```
trusted_networks !192.168.1.1
```

Block the given IP address?

I'm aware of being able to block the IP address using IPtables - I'm just wondering is there any way to do it using SpamAssasin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trusted_networks` is not the correct way of doing this within SpamAssasin.

However, this can be done by setting a `blacklist_from` filter. The [docs](http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.4.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html#whitelist_and_blacklist_options) explain this well.

If the IP you are trying to block is spam, it may also be worth using `iptables` or `ufw` to block it as well, for added security.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -j REJECT
```